# xpages using https how to access another application

Tags: xpages

We access an application from another using `DbColumn` ( I want to access a view from another database ) and for the dbname we are using:

```
`var a = "domain/company" + "!!" + "MyBase.nsf"`

@Unique(@DbColumn(a, "vwMy", 0)
```

We changed from http to https and we have an error now: for SelectItems. DbColumn is used within a combobox.

how can I acces another database other way? So that it can work using https also.

Comment: Is the other database on the same server? If another server, is it in the same domain?

Comment: Yes, it is on the same server: server/CompanyName.

Comment: I don't think https is the issue. What does the error say? Check the XPages log file on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following code:

```
var dbname = "";

if(@ClientType()=="Notes"){
dbname = "server/Company" + "!!" + "MyBase.nsf";
}
else if (@ClientType()=="Web"){

 dbname = session.getServerName() + "!!" + "MyBase.nsf";
}
```

It looks that specifying it in a string "server/Company" didn't work in my case when I'm using it on the browser.
Also it seems the https hadn't influence this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access another database on the same server you can use

@Unique(@DbColumn("names.nsf"($PeopleGroupsFlat)", 2))

Comment: I think it was my mistake: it is name.nsf = a random . nsf, not names.nsf.

Comment: Do you mean the value of the random nsf is computed?